# Sitecore Analytics report anonymous users vs members

Tags: reporting, sitecore, sitecore-dms

I'm trying to set up a report in Sitecore Analytics that will report on the number of visitors split by members/non-members. I've looked in the Visitor and Visits tables but as far as I can see there's nothing that tells me if it was an anonymous user or not. Do I need to set up visitor profile to be able to get what I want, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DMS has a field for this, Visitors.ExternalUser, but you need to write code to populate it.  Include this code in your Login handler:

```
if (Tracker.IsActive) 
{
  Tracker.Visitor.ExternalUser = Sitecore.Context.User.DisplayName.ToLower(); 
}
```

You can then compare the number of visitors with this field populated to the total number of visitors.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't got enough rep to vote up yet so will go back and do it as soon as I do.